# How to write into Rspec output log file from rspec test case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have Rspec test cases but I want write some data from variables into Rspec output file for further processing, so how to write into output file generated by `--out rspec_results.html`

Comment: Its a little unclear what you are asking, can you reword your question.

Comment: Maybe you want to redirect rspec output into file? In this case unix stream might help you: `rspec spec > rspec_result.txt`

Comment: I want to write into Rspec output file from my ruby Rspec testcase code..like writing in std out

Comment: @nattfodd thanks but  I have generated Rspec report with me. I just want to add some data to that file from testcases itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `spec_helper.rb` file write down this code

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = 'spec/examples.txt'
end
```